# Restart consumption from last checkpoint in EventHostProcessor

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

Given an implementation of the EventHostProcessor, how can I force replay of events from the last checkpoint within the same processor?

To be clear, assume my partition is 100 deep and I have consumed 10 messages. When I invoke this replay method, I would then want `onEvent` to return the first message from my previously consumed 10.

In C# this seems possible through the use of the `Stopwatch` but I do not see the Java equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be that you can either checkpoint to the high-water mark of the last consumed EventData or you can checkpoint to another EventData instance.

Such as `context.checkpoint(data);`

There does not seem to be a way to arbitrarily rewind to an earlier event within an EventProcessorHost.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is that using Java [`StopWatch`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html) class of [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library and following the C# code in the tutorial [`Receive events from Azure Event Hubs using the .NET Framework`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-framework-getstarted-receive-eph) to write the same feature code in Java with `azure-event-hubs-java` library (on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java), maven dependency for `EventProcessorHost` [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs-eph)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think it works that way. The stopwatch you reference isn't the same as the stopwatch from reference code. The reference code uses EH checkpoint stopwatch

Comment: I see the confusion. I'm not really interested in timing the call. I'm interested in resetting the checkpoint pointer to a previous point in time. In particular to the last checkpoint.